Where is the large cook promotion?
The time is 8:59 or ...



Where is the large cook promotion?

3,4,2

Partial answers are welcome.  A complete answer will use/explain all of the above.

This magic square has a lot of solutions (maybe someone with better programming skills than me could even calculate how many). However...

If the time is 8:59, then it could also be said to be 1 to 9...

So we'll be using the digits 1 through 9 exactly once each to fill in the square, which then does in fact have a unique solution:



This can be found by realising 7 and 5 can only go in the right hand column, and deducing the remaining combinations from there

Now

If we take the first 9 letters of the alphabet, and arrange them in the order of the numbers in the grid (297385614), we find the large cook promotion is a...

BIG CHEF AD!!

Which also fits the 3,4,2 enumeration at the end!


Very nice, enjoyed the wordplay in this one!

+1 I am impressed with how quickly you solved this.

@WillOctagonGibson funnily enough it clicked as I thought ‘ooh, using x to y time as a clue would be a good idea for a puzzle…. Oh wait’ :P and got lucky with the final step as it was my first guess, nice puzzle!

What is the meaning of the “3,4,2”?

@DidierL its the enumeration of the final answer, same as like in a crossword, just shows how many letters are in each word of the answer

@BeastlyGerbil I encourage you to edit the 3,4,2 meaning into your answer.

@WillOctagonGibson good idea and done so
